# How to install PECL PAM in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, pam

Can any one help to install [PECL PAM](http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM) in ubuntu 14.04 system . I have tried to install via terminal using sudo aptitude install php5-auth-pam this is what we get "Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "php5-auth-pam" "

Answer (score 0):

You can get the php5 package from the URL:http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5 You can download the package you need and install it.

Comment: thanks a lot @vembutech , let me try to implement the packages listed here